# Hex code using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex

I want to retrieve hexadecimal data from user, using python. How to retrieve the data from user and convert it to hex.

```
 #to read varibales  from Python

STX        =  '\xF7' #hex(input("enter STX Value"))
Deviceid   =   hex(input("enter device id"))
subid      =   hex(input("enter address of the Device and load details"))
Comnd      =   hex(41)
Data       =   hex(01)
EorCode    =   input("enter EOR Code")
ADD_sum    =   '\xF2' #hex(input("Enter Add sum value"))

tuple  = (STX, Deviceid,subid,Comnd,Data,EorCode,ADD_sum)
print tuple
```

i am reading the above data from user,but i am getting output as follows

```
enter device id03
enter address of the Device and load details81
enter EOR Code32
('\xf7', '0x3', '0x51', '0x29', '0x1', '0x20', '\xf2')
```

But i need to be printed as 0x03 and 0x01.

I am very new to PYTHON please help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think it's clear what your *expected* output is here.

Comment: which value are you want to convert into hex. or want to display hex value without 0x?? cause hex of 41 is 29 you got is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for string formatting:

```
>>> "0x{0:04x}".format(42)
'0x002a'
```

So you'll want to modify your lines like so:

```
Deviceid   =   "0x{0:2x}".format((input("enter device id"))
```

Also, if any other Python developer will be looking at this code you may want to look at the Python style guide, [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Following the style guide, your code might look like this:

```
stx = '\xF7'  # hex(input("enter STX Value"))
device_id = hex(input("enter device id"))  # deviceid might also be fine
sub_id = hex(input("enter address of the Device and load details"))
comnd = hex(41)
data = hex(01)
eor_code = input("enter EOR Code")
add_sum = '\xF2'  # hex(input("Enter Add sum value"))

values  = (stx, device_id, sub_id, comnd, data, eor_code, add_sum)
print values  # tuple is a keyword - it's best to *not* override them if possible
```

Of course,

> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is most important.
>
> But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Wayner. Will you explain me how this is working and how we need to use with "input" command

Comment: OP is using 2.7... either the `int(input(`... is redundant or `raw_input` is required instead...

Comment: Good catch. I typically "python3-ify" even my 2 scripts (`from __future__ import ...`) and `try: input = raw_input; range = xrange; except NameError: pass  # Python3!` - so I didn't even notice!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that all you really need is to specify how to print the *numbers*, but `hex` function returns a string.
Because in python, `'10'` is a **string** and this is different from `10`, which is an **int**. Python is dynamicaly, but *strongly* typed language.

So in order to have output you want, you may choose from 2 options:

1. write your own function to convert numbers to hexaxecimal numbers in a format you want and use it instead of `hex`:

   ```
   def myhex(num):
       return '0x%02x' % num
   ```

   this `0x%02x` means - first, `0x` is just normal text which you probably want to prefix all your hexadecimal numbers, `%02x` means: print argument as hexadecimal number of length 2, prefixed with `0` if it's too short (one-digit hexadecimal number).
2. do not convert numbers to hex when reading values (it's probably a good thing to work with numbers *represented as numbers*) and print them formated to your specification at the end:

   ```
   print '(' + ', '.join('%0x02x' % x for x in tuple) + ')'
   ```

   which creates list of all values in `tuple` (btw, *avoid using keywords as your variable names* when possible) converted to correct 2-digit hexadecimal numbers with `0x` prefixes, joins them using `', '` and surrounds them with parentheses. But feel free to change it - I'm just building on your example and trying to duplicate your output.